# Case statement based on the time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table

[image]

Based on the transaction_DT:
if the transaction between **04:00:00 PM to 08:00:00 AM + next day** get "After Hour"

Between **08:00:00 AM to 04:00:00 PM within same day** get "Working Hour"

Using the case statement it is not works!

```
CASE
          WHEN   (  Transacton_DT >= TO_DATE ('4:00:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM')
               AND Transacton_DT  <= TO_DATE ('11:59:00 PM', 'HH:MI:SS PM') )
               OR ( Transacton_DT  >= TO_DATE ('12:01:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS AM')
               AND Transacton_DT  <= TO_DATE('8:00:00 AM', 'HH:MI:SS AM') )
          THEN
             'After Hour'
 ELSE
             'Working Hour'
 END AS "Shift"
```

Comment: If transactions are possible "after hours", are they, then, also possible on weekends (meaning, non-working **days**)? Is that something you should be able to differentiate in your query also? Note that this is not a "programming" or "database" question, but a business question; if you don't know the answer, you should ask your business users, not come up with **your** own answer.

Comment: Thank you, business working 24/7 for that i didn't mentioned weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . how about something like this:

```
(case when to_char(transaction_dt, 'HH24:MI') between '08:00' and '16:00'
      then 'Working hours' else 'After hours'
 end)
```

Your code doesn't work because you are comparing a value with a time component only (well a default date component) to one with a date component.

Comment: @mathguy . . . That was more a statement of what the OP was attempting to do.  I revised the wording.

Comment: thank you actually it is not worked I changed it to be:
(case when to_char(transaction_dt, 'HH24:MI') between '08:00' and '23:59'
or to_char(transaction_dt, 'HH24:MI') between '00:00' and '07:59'
      then 'Working hours' else 'After hours'
 end)

Answer (score 0):

```
case 
    when to_char(transaction_dt, 'HH24:MI')  between '08:00' and '23:59' 
    or to_char(transaction_dt, 'HH24:MI') between '00:00' and '07:59' 
    then 'Working hours' 
else 'After hours' end
```